# MPICH2 issue - MPIEXEC starts from command line but not within Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fortran, mpi, mpich

While trying to debug a Fortran code within Visual Studio 2010 mpiexec cannot start the executable, failing with error while connecting to host: "No connection could be made because machine actively refused it (10061)"

MPICH2 appears to be installed correctly, as I can run the same and other programs from the command line, e.g."mpiexec -n 8 cpi".

The program I'm trying to debug links fine and runs for a while, until it crashes, when executed from the command line, as in example above.

Any ideas or suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which compiler do you use? How do you setup the mpi hosts in VS?

Comment: I use Intel Visual FORTRAN Composer XE 2013 SP1. I don't have any special settings for mpi hosts in VS. All of the parallel processes run on the same workstation (HP Z800 w/ 2 four-core processors). No clusters here. MPIEXEC starts from Debugging\Command MPIEXEC -n 7 ($Targetpath). And that part works, but MPIEXEC gets a pushback from the host and exits.